# import data to oracle DB from MongoDB using pymongo running too slow

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, oracle, pymongo, integrated-pipeline-mode

Dears,
I'm going to load data from MongoDB into Oracle DB using python (pymongo) is running too slow and finally got error 'cursor not found'.
also if I use $match $date in my pipe line, and read only some few days it's working, but
actually I need to load whole history for 10 years.

```
pipeline = [
 {"$match":{"create": {"$gte": s_days_ago,"$lte": e_days_ago}}},
 {'$project':{
  '_id':'$_id',
  'address':'$address',
  'latitude':'$latitude',
  'longitude':'$longitude',
  'country':'$country',
  'state':'$state',
  'city':'$city',
  'create':'$create',
}}
]
```

so any suggestion would be appreciated for these two questions :

1. help to read fastest
2. how to prevent 'cursor not found error' after a long time

My Full code is mentioned below :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import ReadPreference
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

E_DAYS_AGO = 18
S_DAYS_AGO = 20
today = datetime.now()    
s_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=S_DAYS_AGO)
e_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=E_DAYS_AGO)

connection = MongoClient('10.1.1.1',27017)
db = connection.get_database('mydb', read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
collection = db.location

pipeline = [
  {'$project':{
  '_id':'$_id',
  'address':'$address',
  'latitude':'$latitude',
  'longitude':'$longitude',
  'country':'$country',
  'state':'$state'
     }}
    ]

 df = pd.DataFrame() 

 for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline): 
 df = df.append(doc,ignore_index=True)

 df = df.fillna('')
 df['_id'] = df['_id'].apply(lambda x: (str(x).replace('DBRef(',''))) \
                     .apply(lambda x: (str(x).replace(', ObjectId(',''))) \
                     .apply(lambda x: (str(x).replace('))',''))) \
                     .apply(lambda x: (str(x).replace("'",''))) 
    
 df = df.reindex(columns= ['_id','address','latitude','longitude','state','country'])

 db = cx_Oracle.connect('bi/mypass@1.1.1.1:1521/orcl')
 cursor = db.cursor()

 cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE location")
 sql='INSERT INTO BI.location VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8)'

 df_list = df.values.tolist()
 n = 0
 for i in df.iterrows():
     cursor.execute(sql,df_list[n])
     n += 1

 db.commit()
 cursor.close
 db.close
```

Comment: Use `executemany()`, not `execute()`, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html.  You'll also find the 'Thin' mode of the latest release of cx_Oracle (now called python-oracledb) is faster, see see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) and the new doc link https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually the insert into oracle works well in some seconds, the main issue is regarding the loop for " collection.aggregate(pipeline) " which is takes hours

Comment: I'll let an expert comment on that.  I'd still recommend `executemany()` on the Oracle side

Answer (score 0):

This fragment:

```
 for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline): 
 df = df.append(doc,ignore_index=True)
```

Reads all the results into a dataframe before processing them one at a time into Oracle. I would recommend your process them one at time i.e. create a single element dataframe and pass that onto Oracle . That is what is causing the delay. You them compound this by running an `apply()` in the dataframe which does a second iteration over the data. Why not do the `apply()` processing while you are creating the dataframe?

In essence, pymongo is not slow, you are processing the whole dataset on the pymongo side twice and then doing simple writes on the Oracle side.

The dataframe looks like a pretty heavyweight object. I think you could do all that preprocessing in a dict, but I am not an Oracle expert so I am not sure what you are doing at the Oracle end.